# Android to BlackBerry 10 porting

Tags: blackberry-10

I am new to blackberry10 platform,I have already developed an application in Android and i want the same application in Blackerry10 and Blackberry Playbook . And I have converted my .apk file to .bar file using Blackberry Graphical Aid. I would like to know if there is any prolem for the application in running to blackberry10 platform  or i have to develop it newly for Blackberry10 environment.

Answer (score 1):

[Download the simulator](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/) and try it out. That's the only way you're going to find out whether it works on BlackBerry 10. Assuming you didn't have any compatibility warnings when you converted your APK to a BAR file you should be fine!

Answer (score 0):

You must read first the documents that describe Android features that are not supported by the BlackBerry Runtime for Android apps on BlackBerry 10.

[Unsupported APIs for BlackBerry 10](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_overview.html)

[BlackBerry Balance Limitations](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_balance.html)

[App Types](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_app_types.html)

[Hardware Features](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_hardware_features.html)

[Software Features](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_software_features.html)

[Intents](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_intents.html)

[App Permissions](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_app_permissions.html)

[Media APIs](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_media.html)

[Media Formats](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_media_formats.html)

Personally i have found some bugs in OS 10.0 that are not documented like

[Blackberry 10, my Android App ported to OS10 doesn´t work in OS 10.0 only in 10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901311/blackberry-10-my-android-app-ported-to-os10-doesnt-work-in-os-10-0-only-in-10)