# Blackberry 10, my Android App ported to OS10 doesn´t work in OS 10.0 only in 10.1

Tags: android, permissions, porting, blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

Our Android application ported to Blackberry 10 only works in Blackberry 10.1 OS when is downloaded from Blackberry App World, we have realized that the app sometimes can´t write or read from the directories created by our app:

Device/misc/android/Android/data/**com.iasi.jorgesys/files/temp/**

Probably we need another perrmission, this is what we have in our Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

anyone?

Update::
I have changed the folder´s name to /grfiles and /grtemp

Update:: /grfiles Ok; /grtemp OK, i think have to change /feed to /grfeed =0

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes can't write or read"? What are the conditions under which it doesn't work?

Comment: hi, sometimes the app can create folders and download some files required to start our app, but suddenly nothing can be write under the directory, only in BB devices with OS 10.0

Comment: I am also having a same issue. Can't able to create or write a file into BB Q5 device.I had used Device/misc/android/Android/data/logfiles/debug1.log. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Hello are you  working on OS 10.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a bug in OS 10.0, must upgrade to OS 10.1 and it works like a charm.
some permissions to write are denied using OS 10.0